# gen_server:call causes server to crash with a noproc

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp

I have a simple server (below). I can create the server with `cell_tracer:start_link()` and this works; I know this because when I repeat the same call, I get an `already_started` error. The problem is that after the server is created, using `cell_tracker:get_cells()` (or doing any `gen_server:call(...)`) on it causes the server to exit with an exception like this:

```
** exception exit: {noproc,{gen_server,call,[cell_tracker,get_cells]}}
     in function  gen_server:call/2 (gen_server.erl, line 180)
```

I can call the `handle_call(get_cells...)` directly, and I get the expected result.

I'm not sure what's happening here. It doesn't give me much information to work with, and I don't see a problem. How can I dig into this further?

```
-module(cell_tracker).
-behavior(gen_server).
-export([start_link/0, stop/0]).
-export([add_cell/1, del_cell/1, get_cells/0]).
-export([init/1,
         handle_cast/2,
         handle_call/3,
         terminate/2,
         handle_info/2,
         code_change/3]).

%% operational api
start_link() ->
  gen_server:start_link({global, ?MODULE}, ?MODULE, [], []).

stop() ->
  gen_server:cast(?MODULE, stop).

%% traking api

add_cell(Cell) ->
  gen_server:call(?MODULE, { add_cell, Cell }).

del_cell(Cell) ->
  gen_server:call(?MODULE, { del_cell, Cell }).

get_cells() ->
  gen_server:call(?MODULE, get_cells).

%% gen_server callbacks

init(Coords) ->
  {ok, Coords}.

handle_cast(stop, Coords) ->
  {stop, normal, Coords}.

handle_call({add_cell, Cell}, _From, Cells) ->
  {reply, ok, [Cell|Cells]};
handle_call({del_cell, Cell}, _From, Cells) ->
  {reply, ok, Cells -- Cell};
handle_call(get_cells, _From, Cells) ->
  {reply, Cells, Cells}.

terminate(unnormal, _State) -> ok.

handle_info(_,_) -> ok.
code_change(_,State,_) -> {ok, State}.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

register the server locally

```
start_link() ->
  gen_server:start_link({local, ?MODULE}, ?MODULE, [], []).
```

or if you register `{global, ?MODULE}` cast, call to `{global, ?MODULE}`

see [gen_server](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/gen_server.html)

Comment: Yes, you must **either** register the process locally and call it locally, **or** register globally and call it globally. They are two separate namespaces.

Answer (score 1):

I have got the same problem working with python ( 2.7 ) and couchdb ( 2.1 ).
The point was I did save document without id. Here is an example

```
import couchdb
server = couchdb.Server('http://admin:PASSWORD@127.0.0.1:5984/')
db = server.create('numbers')
idd, revv = db.save({"taras":"vaskiv"})
```

after this I got this exception

```
431         # Store cachable responses
ServerError: (500, (u'noproc', u'{gen_server,call,[couch_uuids,create]}'))
```

But when I did save document with id, everything seems to work just fine.

```
idd, revv = db.save({"taras":"vaskiv", "_id": "55"})
```